# PHP / Apache File Write Permissions without 777

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I'm trying to avoid 777 permissions for a directory that handles file uploads on a Linux server. PHP/Apache must be able to write to this particular directory, but I don't want to make it world-writable.

What're the best-practices for this?

I am not too familiar with the CLI, so my attempts to solve this using chgrp and chown have not yielded any results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) if supported. You could do something as simple as `setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx,d:u:www-data:rwx /path/to/directory` to allow apache to write to that specific directory (and all later created directories as well)

Comment: @clutterjoe What Linux distribution? Root access or shared hosting? What filesystem? Could you be more specific? Is the directory outside of the web directory? What do you want to achieve? Aand did you try to change the group to the web-server user and set proper permissions (775)?